# Is there some way to make a foobar2000 playlist automatically track and update its file paths?

Tags: windows, windows-10, automation, io, foobar2000

I have a lot of poorly named music files. They are poorly named because when they were digitized or converted, there either was no metadata at all, or it was incomplete/inconsistent, etc.

Manually renaming all the files would/will take me years. I cannot wait that long to start making carefully crafted playlists!

If I create a playlist right now in foobar2000, and then later rename one or more of the files in it, or move them around within the music directory tree, the playlist will obviously break.

Is there some way to make it so that the paths inside it are automatically updated whenever foobar2000 or whatever built-in Windows 10 mechanism detects a change in that directory tree?

I would code this myself if only I knew some way to accomplish it. As far as I know, Windows itself doesn't have the ability to keep track of I/O changes of a given directory tree, and I don't see how I could do this myself from simply observing the files with a script. I wouldn't know what exactly had been done to the file(s). I would just be able to tell that things have changed.

Does foobar2000 have this ability? If not, can you think of a sane way for my (yet to be coded) script to know what exactly changed? Like a nice computer-paresable list such as:

```
Renamed: X to Y
Deleted: X
Moved: X to Y
```

Etc. Where X and Y are full paths to files.

Comment: A) you shouldn't have "foobar2000" in your title. That doesn't help people looking to solve a similar problem  B) You could code something that identifies files based on a hash then it's independent of filenames.

Comment: Same question (no answers though) here https://superuser.com/questions/1756623/is-there-some-wayto-make-file-rename-move-aware-foobar2000-playlists

Comment: So Robocopy has a "pretend to copy, but log only, don't copy" switch and PowerShell has a "what if I ran" feature. Either could be used to create a snapshots of log files which could then be compared for changes. Checksums and a database could be used in a similar manner. (For an idea of workflow see, for example: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/480708/ ) The initial checksum would take a long time, but if you compare logs, you get a short list of candidates.

Answer (score -2):

As far as I remember, when you add a folder with music to Media Library, it is monitored in real time:
[image]

**EDIT:** Sorry, I misunderstood your problem then :/

There is an old plugin called [foo_playlist_revive](https://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Playlist_Revive_(foo_playlist_revive)). Maybe it will help. As far as I tested it now, it works.

Comment: Yes, that is true, but only for the files available to add into playlists. Not the playlists themselves.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).